# Javascript/canvas renderer for CAD/AutoCAD files

Tags: javascript, three.js, autocad, cad

Does anyone know if there's a parser for autocad/cad formatted files in javascript? Or perhaps something server side which can translate cad files to collada so that three.js (and some of the other engines) could read them?

Thanks very much for any links and pointers.

Comment: Just a side note, JavaScript is the perfect choice for rendering. Consider using [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL).

Comment: sadly one of the targets is IE9... so no webgl :-(

Comment: Yup. 10, finally actually does something and surprisingly is working quite good.

Comment: @Bakudan huh? webgl in IE10? really?

Comment: Ups, this was not not IE. Wow, Win8 with IE10, still don't have webgl support...

Answer (score 2):

Python has an autocad lib http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyautocad/ It provides json export. It works on Windows.

I think it can be a server-side solution if Python running on a Windows server is acceptable for you.

Comment: Looks really interesting.. I'm going to keep the thread open for a bit in the hope that someone knows a browser based solution (or perhaps a php one which would be preferable)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [OpenCascade](http://www.opencascade.org/) and the [community edition](https://github.com/tpaviot/oce) developed in C++. There seems to be an experimental [COLLADA exporter](https://github.com/tpaviot/oce/wiki/COLLADA-exporter) done by the community edition.

If you prefer working with Python, you should see the [pythonOCC](http://www.pythonocc.org/) project and particularly what they've done with Three.js: [article](http://www.pythonocc.org/news/experimental-webgl-renderer-towards-cad-in-a-browser/) and [sources](http://code.google.com/p/pythonocc/source/browse/branches/webgl).